# Jekyll: how to not interpret jekyll / ruby lines in a code snippet (rouge)?

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I have this snippet of code in a Jekyll post:

```
{% highlight html linenos %}
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

    {% include head.html %}

    <body>
    [...]
    </body>

</html>
{% endhighlight %}
```

I would like that for example the line `{% include head.html %}` is not interpreted when rendering the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround code with

```
 {% raw %}
```

And

```
{% endraw %}
```

> If you are using a language that contains curly braces, you will
>   likely need to place {% raw %}and {% endraw %} tags around your code.

More at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

Comment: Makes sense didnt see that one!
Thanks